# How can we sort js Objects with a double condition

Tags: javascript

How can we sort these objects upper->bottom, and the same time Left->Center->Right ?

```
{value: "upperRight"}
{value: "upperLeft"}
{value: "bottomRight"}
{value: "bottomCenter"}
{value: "bottomLeft"}
```

Comment: What have you tried ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- `split` each `value` at `/(?=[A-Z])/` to get their vertical and horizontal positions. This will create an array like this: `["upper", "Right"]`
- Destructure the array to get them to 2 separate variables
- Create 2 priority objects. One for mapping the order of vertical positions and the other for horizontal
- First `sort` based on the `vertical` priority. If they both have the same priority, `vertical[a1] - vertical[b1]` will return 0. So, `||` will sort them based on the `horizontal` part

```js
const array=[{value:"upperRight"},{value:"upperLeft"},{value:"bottomRight"},{value:"bottomCenter"},{value:"bottomLeft"}];

const vertical = {
  "upper": 1,
  "bottom": 2
}

const horizontal = {
  "Left": 1,
  "Center": 2,
  "Right": 3
}

array.sort((a,b) => {
  const [a1, a2] = a.value.split(/(?=[A-Z])/)
  const [b1, b2] = b.value.split(/(?=[A-Z])/)
  
  return vertical[a1] - vertical[b1] || horizontal[a2] - horizontal[b2]
})

console.log(array)
```

If the `split` operation is expensive, you can add a `map` operation to get all the split values before hand and sort them.

Answer (score 1):

Array.prototype.sort() allows you to specify a comparison function. Just set some basic rules on how you score a string. For example:

- "Upper" is worth 10 points
- "Bottom" is worth 0 points
- "Left" is worth 2 points
- "Center" is worth 1 point
- "Right" is worth 0 points.

Subtract the two scores from each other in your comparison function and use the result as the return value.

```js
var objects = [
  { value: 'upperRight' },
  { value: 'upperLeft' },
  { value: 'bottomRight' },
  { value: 'bottomCenter' },
  { value: 'bottomLeft' }
];

function scoreString(s) {
  var score = 0;
  if (s.indexOf('upper') > -1) score += 20;
  if (s.indexOf('Left') > -1) score += 2;
  else if (s.indexOf('Center') > -1) score += 1;
  return score;
}

var sorted = objects.sort(function (a, b) {
  return scoreString(b.value) - scoreString(a.value);
});

console.log(sorted);
```